# Jquery row index based select list population

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I am creating dynamic fields inside html table using following code:

```
$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><select class="form-control dynamic" id="governorate" name="governorate[]" data-dependent="destination">@if ($Governorate->count()) @foreach($Governorate as $gov)<option value={{$gov->governorate}}>{{$gov->governorate}}</option>@endforeach @endif                                          </select></td>            <td><select class="form-control" id="destination" name="destination[]"></select></td></tr>');  

      });
```

[image]
It contains two drop down select lists
Governorate and Destinations where second is being populated after the selection of first. It working fine.

I just want to populate second list based upon row index, currently only first row select list is being re-populated upon change of first one in any row.

```
$('table').on('change', '.dynamic', function() {

  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var select = $(this).attr("id");
   var value = $(this).val();
   var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
   var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

   $.ajax({ 
    url:"{{ route('dynamicdependent.fetch') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
    success:function(result)
    {
     $('#'+dependent).html(result);
    }

   });
  }
 });
```

Comment: What does the actual HTML output look like once you've made the `append()`. It looks like you're repeating `id` attributes when they must be unique and that's causing the problem. You'd be better off using common classes instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added image to show how new row is being created dynamically

Comment: Unfortunately images are not helpful. We need to see the actual code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan html code is written inside jquery as shown above

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The html of table is being created dynamically after I press button Add and this output is not being shown inside inspector tab of firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding row index in the following way:

```
$('table').on('change', '.dynamic', function() {
var row = $(this).closest('tr');

  if($(this).val() != '')
  {
   var select = $(this).attr("id");
   var value = $(this).val();
   var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
   var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

   $.ajax({ 
    url:"{{ route('dynamicdependent.fetch') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
    success:function(result)
    {
     $('#'+dependent,row).html(result);
    }
    }

   });
  }
 });
```